# Inconsistant boot, hangs during, I think it's GPU related

Tags: boot, nvidia, xorg, gdm, gpu-driver

Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS

Installed NVIDIA driver last week, haven't had problems until now. Boot hangs at different part of boot usually. ~ 1 in 6 attempts boots without issue. advanced booting into recovery mode, older release seems to help. Shutdown sometimes doesn't work, with the error message: "Waiting for process: Xorg.wrap, gpu-manager
Sending SIGKILL to remaining processes...
Sending SIGKILL to  PID 1519 (Xorg.wrap).
Sending SIGKILL to PID 2017 (gpu-manager).
Waiting for process: gpu-manager, Xorg.wrap"

This is my first post, so apologies for etiquette and formatting deficiencies in advance.

Error log from failed boot, red messages only:

```
: [drm:nv_drm_load [nvidia_drm]] *ERROR* [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00000100] Failed to allocate NvKmsKapiDevice

[drm:nv_drm_probe_devices [nvidia_drm]] *ERROR* [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00000100] Failed to register devic

BUG: kernel NULL pointer dereference, address: 0000000000000040#PF: supervisor read access in kernel mode

#PF: supervisor read access in kernel mode

#PF: error_code(0x0000) - not-present page

systemd[2]: Failed to start Detect the available GPUs and deal with any system changes.
pulseaudio[1843]: Error opening PCM device front:0: No such file or directory
```

Comment: I followed this guide: https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-install-the-nvidia-drivers-on-ubuntu-22-04. It seemed to work fine as running games after the driver install had much better performance. I used the CLI portion of guide. current driver is nvidia-driver-530-open - distro non-free recommended

Comment: The reason I installed the drivers is when installing Ubuntu initially the nvidia drivers negatively impacted the performance drastically. So I used whatever generic drivers came with Ubuntu. As I got used to Ubuntu I started using Windows less and less (dual boot on laptop). I've booted windows like twice in 6 months now. I decided I wanted a couple steam games on Ubuntu and decided to try to install nvidia drivers again. I didn't have any issues for a week after install, and yesterday trying to boot I run into these issues. I perform apt update everyday, maybe a recent update caused issues?

Comment: I don't recall if i accepted proprietary drivers during the initial install. I likely followed whatever was recommended during install, if ubuntu even prompts for it. As for for the nvidia driver guide, in bash I input: "ubuntu-drivers devices",  "sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall". Iirc, auto install did not install a nvidia driver, as I ended up inputing "sudo apt install nvidia-driver-nvidia-driver-530-open". I rebooted, and things seemed to work. Until now. The initial Ubuntu install was roughly 18 months ago, and I don't recall what graphics driver was installed. Should I reinstall Ubuntu?

Comment: It seems to be stable using an older release from the grub menu. I'll just work around it for the time being and see if I can't track down the problem. Thanks for your help, I appreciate the effort!

Comment: Can you try bootoption nogpumanager?

Comment: **Welcome to the Ask Ubuntu community.** Please edit your question with any updates and new information regarding your issue instead of adding additional comments, as this can become difficult to fully understand the current state of your problem. Thanks